# Shell: why does while loop processing additional char

Tags: shell

This is my simple shell script

```
root@Ubuntu:/tmp# cat -n script.sh 
     1  echo
     2  while x= read -n 1 char
     3  do
     4   echo -e "Original value = $char"
     5   echo -e "Plus one = `expr $char + 1`\n"
     6  done < number.txt
     7  echo
root@Ubuntu:/tmp#
```

And this is the content of `number.txt`

```
root@Ubuntu:/tmp# cat number.txt 
12345
root@Ubuntu:/tmp#
```

As you can see on the code, I'm trying to read each number and process it separately. In this case, I would like to add one to each of them and print it on a new line.

```
root@Ubuntu:/tmp# ./script.sh 

Original value = 1
Plus one = 2

Original value = 2
Plus one = 3

Original value = 3
Plus one = 4

Original value = 4
Plus one = 5

Original value = 5
Plus one = 6

Original value = 
Plus one = 1


root@Ubuntu:/tmp#
```

Everything looks fine except for the last line. I've only have 5 numbers, however it seems like the code is processing additional one.

```
Original value = 
Plus one = 1
```

Question is how does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the input file `number.txt` contains a complete line, which is terminated by a line feed character (LF). (You can verify the input file is longer than 5 using `ls -l`.) `read` eventually encounters the LF and gives you an empty `char` (stripping the terminating LF from the input as it would without the `-n` option). This will give you `expr  +  1` resulting in `1`. You can explicitely test for the empty `char` and terminate the while loop using the test `-n` for non-zero length strings:

```
echo "12345" | while read -n 1 char && [ -n "$char" ]; do echo "$char" ; done
```